# How do I iterate through JSON files stored in GCP bucket in different folders. Example; | Bucket/Dict/Folder2/file.json Bucket/Dict/Folder1/file.json

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vertex-ai, cloud-document-ai

I have dumped JSON files from DOCAI to GCP but each file is stored in individual folder, although they are in the same bucket on Cloud Storage. I am not able to iterate through the JSON files stored in the blobs.

I have used 'Batch Processing' document provided on GCP which helps me generate output but the JSON files are created in separate folders. I have trained a Custom Document Extractor which I am validating on 50 documents using this code. My aim is to read these JSON files and create a dataframe of the output by appending them all

[Batch processing](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#documentai_batch_process_document-python)

```
# Reading gcs files with gcsfs
import gcsfs
import json
import pandas as pd

gcs_file_system = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project="project-name")
gcs_json_path = "file0.json" 
with gcs_file_system.open(gcs_json_path) as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)
    
    
djson = pd.json_normalize(json_dict, record_path=['entities'])
djson
```

I am using this code to read the JSON files by providing the gcs_path but I am able to read only one file.

Comment: So you're trying to [list objects in a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects)?

Comment: Folders does not exist. You can iterate over all the object in the bucket and keep/select only those which match your pattern (you can use regex for that). When you have only the target objects, do whatever you want with them

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier for you to use the [Document AI Toolbox Python SDK](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/toolbox).

There are built-in functions for getting `Document` JSON files from Google Cloud Storage after batch processing and functions for exporting entities to a dictionary, which can be converted to a `DataFrame`.

There is a method [`from_gcs()`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai-toolbox/latest/google.cloud.documentai_toolbox.wrappers.document.Document#google_cloud_documentai_toolbox_wrappers_document_Document_from_gcs) but this can currently only create a single Wrapped Document from a single document output in GCS.

You can try something like this:

```py
from google.cloud.documentai_toolbox import document
from google.cloud.documentai_toolbox import gcs_utilities
import pandas as pd

# Given Document.JSON files in path gs://bucket/path/to/folder
gcs_bucket_name = "bucket"
gcs_prefix = "path/to/folder"

# Each "Wrapped Document" corresponds to a single input file.
wrapped_documents = [
    document.Document.from_gcs(
        gcs_bucket_name=gcs_bucket_name, gcs_prefix=directory
    )
    for directory, files in gcs_utilities.list_gcs_document_tree(
        gcs_bucket_name, gcs_prefix
    ).items()
    if files != [""]
]

# Entities from all Documents
all_entities = [wd.entities_to_dict() for wd in wrapped_documents]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(all_entities)
```

Alternatively, you can use the Batch Process Operation ID to get documents from a single batch.

```py
from google.cloud import documentai
from google.cloud.documentai_toolbox import document
import pandas as pd

# ... Batch Processing Code
operation = client.batch_process_documents(request)

# Format: `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/operations/OPERATION_ID`
operation_name = operation.operation.name

# Each "Wrapped Document" corresponds to a single input file.
wrapped_documents = document.Document.from_batch_process_operation(operation_name)

# Entities from all Documents
all_entities = [wd.entities_to_dict() for wd in wrapped_documents]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(all_entities)
```